# GraphQL + SQLalchemy, nested types cannot be detected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphql

I'm working on small app using graphql and sqlalcehmy. Currently faced one issue and I cannot overcome it.

I have a model of skill which looks like this:

```
class Skill(Base):
    __tablename__ = "skills"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    category = Column(String)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    img_path = Column(String)
    users = relationship("User", secondary="user_skills", back_populates="skills")
```

In one of my endpoints when I'm fetching all skills, I also need to group them by category.

```
def get_all_skills(db: Session) -> List[CategorizedSkill]:
    skills = db.query(model.Skill).order_by(model.Skill.category).all()
    if not skills:
        raise DBRecordNotFound("No skills uploaded")
    _categories = {}
    for skill in skills:
        if skill.category not in _categories:
            _categories[skill.category] = []
        _categories[skill.category].append({"name": skill.name, "img_path":skill.img_path})
    categories = [{"category": k, "skills": v} for k,v in _categories.items()]
    return categories
```

And the type is following:

```
class Skill(BaseModel):
    name: str
    img_path: str

class CategorizedSkill(BaseModel):
    category: str
    skills: List[Skill]
```

My grahpql types are simillar:

```
@strawberry.type
class SkillTypeBase:
    name: str
    img_path: str

@strawberry.type
class SkillTypeUser:
    category: str
    skills: List[SkillTypeBase]
```

And my query:

```
    @strawberry.field
    def all_skills(self, info) -> List[SkillTypeUser]:
        return get_all_skills(db=info.context["db"])
```

One the first sight everything looks correct. Also when I print `get_all_skills`, I receive the correct output. However graphql keeps throwing me an error...

query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allSkills {
    category
    skills {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and the error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'dict' object has no attribute 'skills'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allSkills",
        0,
        "skills"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like my types are not detected. What might be wrong here?

Am expecting some hints what might be wrong in the above code as on first sight everything looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. in `get_all_skills` I need to create list of instances of CategorizedSkill. I thought that pydantic would convert dict into this model but apparently not.